# Serializer with m2m field with through model. Got AttributeError

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have User model with m2m field with through arg:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    ...
    organizations = models.ManyToManyField(OrganizationV1, blank=True, through="UserOrganizationRole")
    ...

class UserOrganizationRole(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role = models.ForeignKey(Role, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    organization = models.ForeignKey(OrganizationV1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_main_organization = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

And following serializers:

```
class UserOrganizationRoleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = UserOrganizationRole
        fields = ("user", "organization", "role", "is_main_organization")

class CreateUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    organizations = UserOrganizationRoleSerializer(many=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        organizations_data = validated_data.pop("organizations")

        user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)

        for organization in organizations_data:
            UserOrganizationRole.objects.create(
                user=user,
                organization=organization["organization"],
                role=organization["role"],
                is_main_organization=organization["is_main_organization"]
            )
        return user

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('organizations', ...)
```

After POST request i got a `User` and `UserOrganizationRole` instances, but server response throw an error:

```
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `user` on serializer `UserOrganizationRoleSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `OrganizationV1` instance.
Original exception text was: 'OrganizationV1' object has no attribute 'user'.
```

If i specify `write_only=True` in `UserOrganizationRoleSerializer` all work correct with `201 response`, so the problem with data representation.
I don't understand what i'm doing wrong. Can anyone help with that?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved.
By default field `organizations` represented as a list of `OrganizationV1` instances, but we need to work with `UserOrganizationRole`. 
So we have to explicitly specify `source` attribute like this:

```
organizations = UserOrganizationRoleSerializer(many=True, source="userorganizationrole_set")
```